# Refresh sharepoint linked table in access db through excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to refresh sharepoint linked table in access db using excel vba.
I'v created the connection for access db in excel vba

```
 On Error GoTo ExceptionHandle
 Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset

' connect to the Access database
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " & _
"Data Source=C:\sample.accdb;"      
' open a recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
```

but how do i use the method CurrentDb.TableDefs("TableName").RefreshLink . how do i specify the currentdb using with `cn`.

Comment: One option would write the code in Access, then call it from excel. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9472652/calling-access-sub-from-excel

Answer (score 0):

I think ADODB does not support CurrentDb method but DAO does.